# React application caching

Tags: reactjs, react-cache

I am new to React. I have a React application which recently pushed to Production. There were some frontend fixes and again pushed to production. But it is showing the same page after new build. It is taking from cache. But if i remove cache, it is working.

Using react boilerplate (https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate)

I tried searching for Service worker and res.header(cache-control). But nothing seems to be worked.

Below is my webpack prod file

````
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackPwaManifest = require('webpack-pwa-manifest');
const OfflinePlugin = require('offline-plugin');
const { HashedModuleIdsPlugin } = require('webpack');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const S3Plugin = require('webpack-s3-plugin');
// const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const config = require('../../app/config');

module.exports = require('./webpack.base.babel')({
  mode: 'production',

  // In production, we skip all hot-reloading stuff
  entry: [
    require.resolve('react-app-polyfill/ie11'),
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/app.js'),
  ],

  // Utilize long-term caching by adding content hashes (not compilation hashes) to compiled assets
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js',
  },

  // optimization: {
  //   minimize: true,
  //   minimizer: [
  //     new TerserPlugin({
  //       terserOptions: {
  //         warnings: false,
  //         compress: {
  //           comparisons: false,
  //         },
  //         parse: {},
  //         mangle: true,
  //         output: {
  //           comments: false,
  //           ascii_only: true,
  //         },
  //       },
  //       parallel: true,
  //       cache: true,
  //       sourceMap: true,
  //     }),
  //   ],
  //   nodeEnv: 'production',
  //   sideEffects: true,
  //   concatenateModules: true,
  //   splitChunks: {
  //     chunks: 'all',
  //     minSize: 30000,
  //     minChunks: 1,
  //     maxAsyncRequests: 5,
  //     maxInitialRequests: 3,
  //     name: true,
  //     cacheGroups: {
  //       commons: {
  //         test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
  //         name: 'vendor',
  //         chunks: 'all',
  //       },
  //       main: {
  //         chunks: 'all',
  //         minChunks: 2,
  //         reuseExistingChunk: true,
  //         enforce: true,
  //       },
  //     },
  //   },
  //   runtimeChunk: true,
  // },

  plugins: [
    // Minify and optimize the index.html
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
      inject: true,
    }),
    new S3Plugin({
      exclude: /.*\.html$/,
      s3Options: {
        accessKeyId: config.aws.s3.aws_access_key_id,
        secretAccessKey: config.aws.s3.aws_secret_access_key,
        region: 'us-west-2',
      },
      s3UploadOptions: {
        Bucket: config.aws.s3.bucket,
      },
    }),

    // Put it in the end to capture all the HtmlWebpackPlugin's
    // assets manipulations and do leak its manipulations to HtmlWebpackPlugin
    new OfflinePlugin({
      relativePaths: false,
      publicPath: '/',
      appShell: '/',

      // No need to cache .htaccess. See http://mxs.is/googmp,
      // this is applied before any match in `caches` section
      excludes: ['.htaccess'],

      caches: {
        main: [':rest:'],

        // All chunks marked as `additional`, loaded after main section
        // and do not prevent SW to install. Change to `optional` if
        // do not want them to be preloaded at all (cached only when first loaded)
        additional: ['*.chunk.js'],
      },

      // Removes warning for about `additional` section usage
      safeToUseOptionalCaches: true,
      AppCache: false,

      ServiceWorker: {
        events: true,
        publicPath: '/sw.js',
        navigateFallbackURL: '/',
        prefetchRequest: {},
      },
      // Hack
      // This is to skip the warning that OfflinePlugin throws if sw registration is not done
      __tests: {
        ignoreRuntime: true,
      },
    }),

    new CompressionPlugin({
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8,
    }),

    new WebpackPwaManifest({
      name: 'React Boilerplate',
      short_name: 'React BP',
      description: 'My React Boilerplate-based project!',
      background_color: '#fafafa',
      theme_color: '#b1624d',
      inject: true,
      ios: true,
      icons: [
        {
          src: path.resolve('app/images/icon-512x512.png'),
          sizes: [72, 96, 128, 144, 192, 384, 512],
        },
        {
          src: path.resolve('app/images/icon-512x512.png'),
          sizes: [120, 152, 167, 180],
          ios: true,
        },
      ],
    }),

    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /en/),

    new HashedModuleIdsPlugin({
      hashFunction: 'sha256',
      hashDigest: 'hex',
      hashDigestLength: 20,
    }),
  ],

  performance: {
    assetFilter: assetFilename =>
      !/(\.map$)|(^(main\.|favicon\.))/.test(assetFilename),
  },
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use webpack and use hashing (and append it to file names) to generate the files.

Hence whenever you rebuild the app and deploy it on production those hashed files wont be present in the cache and you wont have the cache problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable caching if you don't want it but I guess here you wanted to refresh the cache on new deploys, pls try below

app/app.js - at the end of file

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('offline-plugin/runtime').install(); // eslint-disable-line global-require
}
```

replace with

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const runtime = require('offline-plugin/runtime'); // eslint-disable-line global-require
  runtime.install({
    onUpdating: () => {
      console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdating');
    },
    onUpdateReady: () => {
      console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdateReady');
      // Tells to new SW to take control immediately
      runtime.applyUpdate();
    },
    onUpdated: () => {
      console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdated');
      // Reload the webpage to load into the new version
      window.location.reload();
    },

    onUpdateFailed: () => {
      console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdateFailed');
    },
  });
}
```

internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js

add line 90, under new OfflinePlugin({

```
ServiceWorker: {
        events: true,
      },
```

Comment: Hi, it's been a while but I'm having the same problem. The thing is, I am using vite instead of webpack, any tips on resolving this in vite?